# Why was there a fierce resistance to Axis occupation in Yugoslavia during World War II?

Tags: world-war-two, yugoslavia, the-balkans

First of all the resistance against Germans and Italians erupts straight after the conquering of the country, whereas per example at nearby Greece the guerrilla groups become numerous only at 1943.

And it is from the very beginning also a civil war.

Why was there a civil war and was there a connection between this and the strong resistance to occupation by the Germans/Italians?

Comment: Can you bring some evidence that there was fierce resistance to German or Italian occupation in Yugoslavia, or that it was "more fierce" than that in other occupied countries?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question, but please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help] center, and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what remains unclear to you after reading e.g. [World War II in Yugoslavia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_in_Yugoslavia) and related WP articles? As it stands, the question is a bit too broad.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. As my understanding is that most resistance movements, notwithstanding propaganda by the Western Allies, was predominantly a *socialist* phenomenon, an answer must first the timing of Yugoslavian conquest immediately preceding Operation Barbarossa. However the multi-ethnic composition of Yugoslavia and associated strife (see the 1990's conflicts in Serbia and Bosnia) adds additional depth to the picture. I believe there is an interesting answer awaiting here.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I added a "connective" phrase to improve the question, and joined you in voting to reopen.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Joined by me.